# Say "Hello" to the world in ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, printable-ascii, hello-world

**Challenge:** Produce the following output using as few chars as possible:

```
 _   _      _ _                             _     _ _
| | | | ___| | | ___    __      _____  _ __| | __| | |
| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | |
|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_|
|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___( )   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_)
                    |/
```

**Rules and restrictions:**

- You may not use [FIGLet](http://www.figlet.org/) or any similar tools.  (Otherwise, `figlet Hello, world!` would be a trivial and pretty much unbeatable solution.)
- Your program must consist entirely of printable [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters — specifically, code points 9 (TAB), 10 (LF) and 32 – 126.  (If your language / OS requires CRLF line breaks, you may use those instead of plain LFs.)  Yes, this regrettably disqualifies any language that requires non-ASCII characters (or non-textual data) as part of its syntax.
- The output must look exactly like the example above.  You may, however, include extra whitespace around the output if you want.  You may assume 8-character [tab spacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) (or your chosen platform's native default setting, if it has a consistent one).

Ps. To set the par, I came up with a 199-char Perl solution.  I won't post it yet, though, in case someone comes up with it independently.  (Also, it's kind of cheesy.)  Of course, this shouldn't discourage you from posting your own solution, even if it's longer.

---

**Update:** Now that [han has beaten it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4378/3191) by one char, here's my cheesy 199-char Perl solution:

```
use Compress'Zlib;say uncompress unpack u,'M>-I]BT$*`S$,`^]YQ=R:0,&_Z<DP?8@?WVQJ]E2J"%E$$@)R(/(/MCJ*\U!OM`Z#=5`4Y>6M=L\L%DMP&DB0V.4GQL&OOGB$4:%`4TT4!R8O-Z(^BTZWNV?>F86K:9+""-35*-LNC:T^D:_$#%^`";"DD0'
```

It's very similar to [D C's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4361/3191) (and all the other zlib/gzip-based solutions in various languages), except that I used [uuencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) instead of [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for the compressed text and a few other minor golfing tricks.

---

**Update 2**: I think it's time to officially accept a winner.  The first place goes to [konsolenfreddy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3307/konsolenfreddy)'s PHP code, since, however you count the chars, it *is* the shortest submitted so far.  In fact, combining it with the optimized DEFLATE stream from my 199-char Perl code yields an even shorter 176-char solution:

```
<?=gzinflate(base64_decode("fYtBCgMxDAPvecXcmkDBv+nJMH2IH99savZUqghZRBICciDyD7Y6ivNQbwOg3VQFOXlrXbPLBZLcBpIkNjlJ8bBr754hFGhQFNNFAcmLzeiPotOt7tn3plq2mSwgjU1SjbLo2tPpGvxAxfgA"));
```

However, I do think that [han](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3031/han) deserves a special honorary mention for getting so close without using any pre-written decompression tools.  Congratulations to both of you, and a happy new year to everyone!

Comment: Ok, I have to do this one in C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 137 bytes

```
"9&BO]h>&)>3ieuCoKVKVnuOoT'E-^Z(1.3u[);h1[RTOGqTZkoQx?KMy&9ctG&*y~HxR9%GYn.rYMdMcOOq^wXc@%zy*P[*Q"90|E|B"0+1"{%",``_|\/()V'"@]}R.1 |t54/m
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%229%26BO]h%3E%26%29%3E3ieuCoKVKVnuOoT%27E-%5EZ%281.3u[%29%3Bh1[RTOGqTZkoQx%3FKMy%269ctG%26*y%7EHxR9%25GYn.rYMdMcOOq%5EwXc%40%25zy*P[*Q%2290%7CE%7CB%220%2B1%22%7B%25%22,%60%60_%7C%5C%2F%28%29V%27%22%40]%7DR.1+%7Ct54%2Fm&i=&a=1)

It works like this.

1. Start with a big string literal.
2. Convert to integer by decoding as a base-90 number.
3. Convert that number to binary.
4. Runs of `0`s followed by a `1` are translated into non-space characters.
5. All remaining `1`s are replaced with spaces.
6. The resulting string is split into 54-character lines.

Comment: Congrats, looks like this is the shortest solution now! :)

Answer (score 17):

## Perl 5.10 - 195 <strike>198</strike> <strike>202</strike> <strike>203</strike> characters

Here's an entry that does not require any libraries beyond basic regexp matching.  The encoded string is 131 characters, and the code to decode and print it takes up 64 characters (assuming no newline at the end of the source).  The idea is to represent common 3-character strings by lower case letters.

```
s!!xfefxxf\t\t\tf efyx
no| cnocfxefxceyxm|xmn
nm|wtnwtgt/uvy \\| 'ym|w`o|
pepyy/o| _ogrr/ _opn (ml
l lbyly|by( )fiihyjm lb,y_
\t\tf |/!;s!\w!substr'(_)\___   \_/|_| |  V \ / _',-95+ord$&,3!eg;say
```

The encoder is a lot longer and unfortunately not very readable right now.  The basic idea is to use dynamic programming to find the shortest encoding for each line, given a fixed set of string substitutions.  The string of substitutions on the last line was built by trial and error, and it is possible that another string of substitutions might lead to a shorter program than above.

One trick here is that some substitutions are shorter than 3 characters long: due to the way perl `substr` works, `x` is replaced by ' `_`' and `y` by '`_`'.  The latter is necessary because `\w` in the regex matches '`_`', which is then replaced by '`(_)`'.

Comment: +1, very nice. You can save 2 chars by replacing `print` by `say`

Comment: @M42: As far as I could figure out, on perl 5.10 to use `say` you need to either do `use 5.010;` or run the script as a one-liner with `perl -E 'script here'`.  The former makes the code longer and the latter is not appropriate for a multi-line script.  Did I miss something?

Comment: The `-E` doesn't count in number of char.

Comment: @M42: Maybe I'm being thick, but right now I can't see how to use `-E` profitably with a multi-line script that includes both single quotes and backslashes.

Comment: Per [this meta thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), "the `-M5.01` is free".  So feel free to use `say` if you want.

Comment: Ps. You can save a few more chars by using `s''...'` instead of `$_=q!...!`; just remember to escape the single quote.  With that and `say` instead of `print` (and leaving out the last newline), I get this down to 198 chars.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Ok, thanks! I edited the solution.

Comment: BTW, I tried using tabs instead of `#` for the long runs of whitespace and got your solution down to 190 chars.  I wonder if going below 184 chars is possible -- that would beat all the zlib-compressed solutions so far.

Answer (score 14):

### Brainfuck - 862 characters:

```
>++++[<++++++++>-]>-----[<---->---]<+++>>--[<+>--]<---<<.>.<...>.<....
..>.<.>.<.............................>.<.....>.<.>.>>++++++++++.<.<<.
>>.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>...>.<<.>>.<<.>>.<<.>...<....>..<......>.....<..>.<
.>..>.<<.>>.<<.>..>.<<.>>.<<.>>.>.<.<<.>>.<.>.<<.>>.>>>-[<->+++++]<---
-.<<<<.>.<.>---.+++<.>>.<<.>>.>>.<<<<.>.<.>---.<...>.<.>.<.>>>>.<<<.<.
>>>>.<<<<.>>>>.<<<<.>+++.<.>---.>.<<.>>>>>>---[<+>+++++++]<++.<<<<+++.
.>.<<.>>.>>.<<<<.>.+.-<.>>.<<.>>.>.<.<<..>.<..>>.<<..>..>>>.<<<<.>>.<<
.>>.<<.>>>>>+.<<<<.>>>>+.<<<<<.>>.<<...>---.<.>------.<..>.<.>>>>.<<<<
.>>>>>-.<<<<+++++++++.>>>>+.<<<<<.>>.<<.>>.<<..>>.<<.>>.<<.>>>>>-.<<<<
.>.<<.>>.<.>.>.<.<.>.<<.>>.<.>.<---.+++...>.<.>.<.>.<---.+++...>>>>.<<
<<<.>>>>>+.<<<<<...>---.+++.>>>.<<<---.+++.>>>.<<<<.>---.+++...>>>.<<.
<.>.<<..>>.<.>.<---.+++..>>>>+++.<<<<.>>>>----.<<<<.>>>>+.<<.<<<......
..............>>.>>.<.
```

Comment: Note that this code apparently assumes 8-bit cells; I first tried it on an interpreter with 32-bit cells, and it got stuck at `[<---->---]` on the first line. (Presumably it would eventually have finished, but I didn't wait long enough for that.)

Comment: How the heck did you write this in two hours?

Comment: looks like you save ` ')(,/|V\_\n on the first cells and them you just go back and forth printing the needed char (BF Dev text generator?). Nice work BTW

Comment: It does depend on 8 bit wrapping cells. Stores a few common characters like you said, but not all. Also does things like switches between '\' and '_' in one cell where they are close enough to do so.

Comment: @JBernardo, BF dev text generator gave code much bigger than this. It would take a much more complicated generator to beat this I think.

Answer (score 9):

### Python (2.x), 194 characters

```
print'eNo9T8ENxCAMe5cp/DsqVco2fSH5BsnwZ4ccEIhxbAIgAK9KvDRwGBEjsSfJA6r2N7EISbmrpbLNKFRYOABaC6FAEYkPW/Ztm1t7Z1S3ydtHuV4ooolEV6vPyJ2XH8kGE7d9DAVMhFUte6h7xv5rxg8sf0Qc'.decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

Comment: This answer just made my day xD. I would have never thought I would see a codegolf that actually uses zip&base64 to decrease string size

Answer (score 4):

This answer is longer than just printing the string; however, just for the fun of it, here it is:

### Python, 485 characters ☺

```
import sys

data= ',C6UBKq.)U^\\ 8[hHl7gfLFyX6,;p\'SlYpN@K-`Kbs#fSU+4o~^_h\\dJDy{o9p?<GnLTgG{?ZM>bJE+"[kHm7EavoGcS#AQ^\\>e_'
table= " _|\\/(\n)V'`,"
key= (0,(1,((((7,5),(6,(8,(11,(9,10))))),(4,3)),2)))

number= 0
for char in data:
    number= number*95 + ord(char) - 32

mask= 1<<655
decoder= key
while mask:
    index= mask & number and 1
    try:
        decoder= decoder[index]
    except TypeError:
        sys.stdout.write(table[decoder])
        decoder= key[index]
    mask>>= 1
```

Since I have one of the shortest ASCII representations of the compressed original text, I must have the longest scrollbar in my code! It's a win! :)

Comment: AKA “my scrollbar is longer than yours”

Comment: This solution can be golfed down to 254 characters.  Do you mind if I edit in the shorter version?

Comment: @han: Of course the character count can be reduced; however, I didn't write this one as a serious candidate. So let this one be voted for its own merit, and write another answer using as much or as little of this answer as you like :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll pass unless someone else is really interested.  I just wanted to point out that this solution can be made significantly shorter than the original text.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript, <del>273</del> <del>265</del> 264 characters

```
" _2_22_ _2222222226_26_ _10 0 3_0 | 3_2 32233_6_ 30 30 |10_0/ _ 4 0/ _ 424 4 /4 / / _ 4| '30/ _` 01|6_6|63/ 0 (_) |24 V6V / (_) 060 (_0_|1|_0_|43_|_543_( )24_/4_/ 43_/56543,_(_)12222226|/".replace(/\d/g,function(a){return'| |,\n,   ,__,\\,|_|,  '.split(',')[a]})
```

:(

Comment: Save the space after the `return`, -1 char :)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, <s>194</s> 189 characters

```
php -r'=gzinflate(base64_decode("dU/BDcQgDPszhX+lUqVs0xeSb5AMf3ZI+7qDACa2EwABeNXR4M/goxqJPUm+oLinEishKTdbKtuMQsTCC6C1EApUInHIvOlP+9zbO6PaTZ6+ynZDEZ1INFuNRu5z+ZVsMHHax1DAibCqZRdVZ/z6esYX"));'
```

It's basically the same as the Python and Perl answer, slightly shorter

Comment: The `php -r'=...'` trick doesn't seem to work for me, but you could just use `<?=...` for 184 chars.  Also, your output seems to have an extra space where the `r` and `l` meet.

Comment: OSX 5.3.6 works fine with the `-r'=..'`. does the `php -r` not count? It's included in my 189chars...

Comment: Generally, the name of the interpreter doesn't count.  For command line options, I've been going by [this meta thread](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions); PHP's `-r` switch is something of a borderline case, though, since, besides just taking code as a parameter and running it, it also modifies the parsing environment slightly compared to running the code from a file.  I'd be inclined to count it as 2 extra chars -- which incidentally puts it even with `<?`.

Answer (score 3):

> In other languages: [**C** (original version), 209 chars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/20382/1); [**Perl**, 200 chars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/20382/4).

### J, <s>167</s> 160 chars (47 + 113)

Another no-builtin-compression submission. Uses a pretty straightforward variable-length encoding, encoding each character as a series of 1 bits and separating characters by 0 bits. The compressed string is a mere 113 characters.

```
('a _|\/',CR,'()V`,'''){~#;.2,(6$2)#:40-~3&u:'8H1(((((H:f[4ZS4ZP2(RPMAMANf[>CZD[F;I[OVFF;TgfS5aGd[7T9JW4[eG[+Of7ddg?d[.AfT]WUASE=S>bSdgI]cS[RWBYSE?gSeG_X(()WG('
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python (2.7.x), 218 characters

```
import base64,zlib;
print zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode("eNo9T8ENxCAMe5cp/DsqVco2fSH5BsnwZ4ccEIhxbAIgAK9KvDRwGBEjsSfJA6r2N7EISbmrpbLNKFRYOABaC6FAEYkPW/Ztm1t7Z1S3ydtHuV4ooolEV6vPyJ2XH8kGE7d9DAVMhFUte6h7xv5rxg8sf0Qc"))
```

Pretty straightforward... not terribly pleased with this attempt.

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, <s>199</s> <s>196</s> 193 characters

```
base64 -d<<<H4sIAAAAAAAAAz1PQQ6AIAw7S+IfelMTk/3GE0l9CI+3HRPYoHQtAxCAMzduGliMiL0NzElygSz+LiYhLWc1VekzDFU6FoCyIxRIYuBgyd7f5+5eGdnv5OWjbA8UUcRAVbORfBN0v5MFTlw2MhQwEVaV7KYu2tv88IgPjUlb7QoBAAA=|zcat
```

Close enough...

EDIT: Down to 193!

Comment: Nice. You could save three more chars by replacing `gzip -d` with `zcat`.

Comment: Using a where-string would save over echo.

Answer (score 2):

### bash, <strike>196</strike> 192

```
base64 -d<<<H4sIAO4SqFMCA3VPQQ7AIAi7+4re5pIl/GYnk+4hPH4U0dOmILUUUBCAPEOBn8Wlao65SW6QudWJSYSUM5sqlQlZJAY2QPiAhSEJx8GSPVWm0TppOa3z1DWqboRZEY7K5pzmMw49kgU6TtXRwiDCpCrZxejTvn7u1l5z59MGKQEAAA|zcat
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 230 characters

```
use Compress::Zlib;
use MIME::Base64;
print uncompress(decode_base64('eNo9T8ENxCAMe5cp/DsqVco2fSH5BsnwZ4ccEIhxbAIgAK9KvDRwGBEjsSfJA6r2N7EISbmrpbLNKFRYOABaC6FAEYkPW/Ztm1t7Z1S3ydtHuV4ooolEV6vPyJ2XH8kGE7d9DAVMhFUte6h7xv5rxg8sf0Qc'));
```

This is basically the same as my Python answer. I'd like to see the 199-character version.. sounds like magic.

Comment: I won't post it quite yet, but you're on the right track.  Of course, I am/was sort of hoping that someone would beat it with a completely different approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <del>294</del> 290 bytes.

The compressed string alone, is <del>151</del> 130 bytes.

This isn't short, but it was really fun to write.

`````
@t=split//,"_|\\/\n()V',`";$b.=substr unpack("B8",chr(-48+ord)),2,6 for split//,'Ph?`@Ooooo1l410````0066600?03l0001PP06600HHB1Q064L4D<8h8^::<DLL4@J0032>1D<90h<>00hHI@6QhYllLX3@`hHI@1Q04P@1Q04@002080R001I^80a074001Q07208P0B0X34ooo`ST';$b=~s/(1)|(0.{4})/$1?" ":$t[ord pack"B8","000$2"]/eg;print$b

@t=split//," _|x"x4 ."\\/\n()V',`";$b.=substr unpack("B8",chr(-48+ord)),2,6 for split//,'4100A0000000001017:8R5HR5@1@05E15R5R;:9Ra4`8\\A<0<30a`<C4C2=URa7PRbP@PG4R<g@P<3D=C4cM288S=RK:HV`EVK1G<d0`LL74`EaV2K1Mg=db0000002ab';$b=~s/1(1.{4})|(..)/$t[ord pack"B8","000".($2?"000$2":$1)]/eg;print$b
`````

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 346 bytes

The compressed string alone, is 111 bytes.

```
@t = split//, " _|\\/\n()V',`";
$k=[0,[1,[2,[[3,4],[[5,6],[7,[[8,9],[10,11]]]]]]]];

$b .= substr unpack("B8", chr(-48+ord)), 2, 6 for split//,'@P900000PBlc<b[<bX:0ZXUIUIVlcFKZLI^Y`LLMhjjW<oJcMGncNHS5MIW]l`ho3lMNgc<IW]V]i[=KUF]KUG[hL^l^^EMeSFiGmNggP001^Pl';

$d = $k;
$o.=$d=~/^\d/?$t[$s=$d,$d=$$k[$_],$s]:($d=$$d[$_],"")for split//,$b;
print $o
```

Trying to understand what the python with `key= (0,(1,((((7,5),(6,(8,(11,(9,10))))),(4,3)),2)))`
was doing, I ended up making a very similar looking perl version.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP 590

obviously, i'm not trying to win, just got interested on trying another compression scheme, altough it can't even beat the simpler 302 plain text PHP solution of just copy-pasting

it works as a bitmap on 10 channels

"golfed"

```
<? $l=['_'=>['l8kqo,ei','9uo6,2fko0','52m0w,5r1c','540lc,5maq','lifeo,19i7ai'],'|'=>[0,'1h39j4,105','1h2k8w,q9x','14l2jk,wlx','1h39j4,wlc','1s,0'],'/'=>[2=>'b9c0,n3kao','pa8,18y68','0,mihog','w,0'],'\\'=>[2=>'pc5,a0zy8','2,0','b9c1,am2kg'],'('=>[3=>'e8,b8lc','1s,4'],')'=>[3=>'3k,2t4w','g,1'],'V'=>[3=>'0,18y680'],'`'=>[2=>'0,g'],"'"=>[2=>'0,6bk'],','=>[4=>'0,g'],];$p=@str_pad;$b=@base_convert;$i=-1;while($i++<5){$h=' ';foreach($l as$c=>$r)if(@$r[$i]){$a=explode(',',$r[$i]);$d=str_split($p($b($a[0],36,2),27,0,0).$p($b($a[1],36,2),27,0,0));foreach($d as$j=>$v)$v&&$h[$j]=$c;}echo"$h\n";}
```

readable

```
<?php
$l = ['_'=>['l8kqo,ei','9uo6,2fko0','52m0w,5r1c','540lc,5maq','lifeo,19i7ai'],
      '|'=>[0,'1h39j4,105','1h2k8w,q9x','14l2jk,wlx','1h39j4,wlc','1s,0'],
      '/'=>[2=>'b9c0,n3kao','pa8,18y68','0,mihog','w,0'],
     '\\'=>[2=>'pc5,a0zy8','2,0','b9c1,am2kg'],
      '('=>[3=>'e8,b8lc','1s,4'],
      ')'=>[3=>'3k,2t4w','g,1'],
      'V'=>[3=>'0,18y680'],
      '`'=>[2=>'0,g'],
      "'"=>[2=>'0,6bk'],
      ','=>[4=>'0,g'],
      ];
$p=@str_pad;
$b=@base_convert;
$i=-1;
while($i++<5){
    $h = str_repeat(' ',54);
    foreach($l as $c=>$r)
        if(@$r[$i]){
        $a = explode(',',$r[$i]);
        $d = str_split($p($b($a[0],36,2),27,0,0).$p($b($a[1],36,2),27,0,0));
        foreach($d as$j=>$v)
            if ($v)
                $h[$j]=$c;
        }
    echo "$h\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pylongolf2, 300 bytes

```
" _   _      _ _                             _     _ _
| | | | ___| | | ___    __      _____  _ __| | __| | |
| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | |
|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_|
|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___( )   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_)
                    |/"~
```

I couldn't find any classy encoding methods, so I'm *probably* not competing.

Answer (score 0):

### Golf-Basic 84, 325

```
:"                     "_Str1t` _   _      _ _ "d`Str1d`Str1t`_     _ _"t`| | | | ___| | | ___    __      _____  _ __| | __| | |"t`| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | |"t`|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_|"t`|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___( )   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_)"t`                    |/"
```

Assuming a calculator could print backticks, backslashes, single pipes, and underscores.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML + JS (223 unicode characters)

Just for fun:

```
<body onload=p.innerHTML=unescape(escape("").replace(/uD./g,''))><pre id=p>
```

NB: you have to save it in a "UTF-8 with BOM" HTML file.

Comment: Nice. Works for me even without a BOM (Firefox 26 / Chromium 31), as long as encoding is set to UTF-8 or auto-detect. Alas, it doesn't qualify under the stated rules ("program must consist entirely of printable ASCII characters"). :-(

Comment: I know, it was just for fun ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 220 byes = script:9 + archive:211

```powershell
tar xOf t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDBisIwEL3nKx71YAUlHyEonjws7KkwW2tKC7UpNe5K6b93Z6apXnaTSfLmzXuZkM7/uP5euaaZUpOAAF16RPDPoEWVbE0yYp5E9AJaXi4jJVhNc1VV0SmJ5VqGFwCvDJYDSoxYU5R9vZ3yBtnJas@UNpKy8RMcNhIjYlVbqXOGmbyWIkixEStZDghhRRVlW@KrxPnXR4w2MdLnw4Xd3rfBtQEldgffF86EvMdQlB7MmaMoqrq5noK7MbOCf4TuEVC3rMgvnCHvi6r@drjXg5vE/TyXCNP0Cw)

The Powershell script to create the archive `t` (see TIO):

```powershell
(
" _   _      _ _                             _     _ _",
"| | | | ___| | | ___    __      _____  _ __| | __| | |",
"| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | |",
"|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_|",
"|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___( )   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_)",
"                    |/"
) | Set-Content f -Force
tar zcfo t f
Get-ChildItem t # output info about archive size
```

Comment: Isn't the archive non-printable?

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$274\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 225.535 bytes

```
Dr_tem[82]\r-reIX3vb/pBNI9@xbV1?^csytMxrA)YVtY.5yfDryr#(K{bAe,YSkOIU9\|tet&RZF_n+!\;TlNE'T3OB{GGqqvpiP 61;Y#nh0^=vOX6@vxmixkmqp<&y<%;b?=|FG&!6*XI*<glXG,bt|0Kv`/lO;OEx7[`$vT4ljhkSGVaE'</\z{uF8L2E2yXU%r\Ws9F;cF4FXZVD}TL?qdxQ;slDX~lyO# K_+lFV52P-Io9a.7JuDaWJ/sAo,lCChg=5 P9^=[B
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJEcl90ZW1bODJdXFxyLXJlSVgzdmIvcEJOSTlAeGJWMT9eY3N5dE14ckEpWVZ0WS41eWZEcnlyIyhLe2JBZSxZU2tPSVU5XFx8dGV0JlJaRl9uKyFcXDtUbE5FJ1QzT0J7R0dxcXZwaVAgNjE7WSNuaDBePXZPWDZAdnhtaXhrbXFwPCZ5PCU7Yj89fEZHJiE2KlhJKjxnbFhHLGJ0fDBLdmAvbE87T0V4N1tgJHZUNGxqaGtTR1ZhRSc8L1xcent1RjhMMkUyeVhVJXJcXFdzOUY7Y0Y0RlhaVkR9VEw/cWR4UTtzbERYfmx5TyMgS18rbEZWNTJQLUlvOWEuN0p1RGFXSi9zQW8sbENDaGc9NSBQOV49W0IiLCIiXQ==)

Boring text compression answer. Doesn't compress very well due to the compressor being much more optimized for words and spaces before words than characters. Fun fact: when designing Fig, I was considering making the compressor use RLE in the character case, but decided to do capitalization instead :(