# ASCII art "Hello-World!"

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, hello-world

Your goal is to write the shortest program that outputs "Hello-World!" as ASCII art.

Rules :

- It must be human readable, I don't care about it's size (cols/rows)
- Output must contain only spaces (" "), sharps ("#") and newlines
- The output must work with a monospaced font (but the letters doesn't necessary use a monospaced font)
- In the result, each character must be separated from each other by at least one space

Please add a title with the language and the number of bytes in your code.

Comment: `bash`: 33 characters – http://pastebin.com/HZ1w8z8g Is this acceptable?

Comment: Why the hyphen though?...

Comment: I suppose to make impossible or unfeasibly hard the use of something predefined like HQ9+.

Comment: What is "The output must work with a monospaced font (but the letters doesn't necessary use a monospaced font)" supposed to mean? Should it be a monospaced font or not?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: The output consisting of spaces and hashes must work with a monospaced font, but the letters represented by the plethora of hashes need not all have the same width.

Comment: Does the case of the letters matter?

Comment: @manatwork if you add the number of characters needed to code `figlet` then it's acceptable :)

Comment: Related, but different: [Say “Hello” to the world in ASCII art](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/say-hello-to-the-world-in-ascii-art)

Comment: @Tomas yes, the case matters.

Comment: @manatwork Technically, that's not forbidden.

Comment: You should have restricted this contest to **ascii-only source and no use of any external fonts**. Would have been much more fun. Let's at least make a sub-contest for that.

Comment: @manatwork How does it make HQ9 hard? All you need is to draw the ASCII ART, replace something with a Q(probably the `.` on `!`), and voila.

Comment: A Unix command. In Unix there used be a command-line tool to achieve just this. In good old matrix-printer days it was necessary to generate a title page for the output of a printing job. So there was a command for just this purpose: the generation of the ASCII-art representation of the arguments. But what was its name? It was so long ago that I forgot it - I did not use it many times anyway, but I was aware of it.

Comment: `In the result, each character must be separated from each other by at least one space`, the chars in "hello world" or the "#"s with which this is printed?

Comment: @avalancha At least one space between the `#` separating each letters

Comment: @ijbalazs: You may be thinking of either [`banner`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_(Unix)) or [`figlet`](http://www.figlet.org/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I absolutely enjoyed this one

## Perl, <strike>126 116 114 102 98</strike>   87 (69) chars (ascii only & no external fonts)

### As of now shortest ascii solution which doesn't use any external fonts.

Well, I wanted to present some elegant solution but @Ilmari Karonen challenged me with `unpack`... shouldn't have done that :-)

Well, this <strike>92 88</strike> **69 chars** code generates the uglish unreadable output identical to
@Ilmari Karonen's:

```
say map{y/01/ #/r}unpack"((b6)7a)*",'eT@j@DE
UUBjdeE
wTujjTA
eUBTddE'
```

More elegant variant without unpack (88 chars):

```
map{print$"x$_,$/x/4/,"#"x!/7/}7&ord,7&ord>>3for'HRyYOKLIIjIRHBa@AJIAIIIJaQHQNSRH'=~/./g
```

But I think such |.|e||.-|||.,d! thing is nothing which resembles Hello-World! and shouldn't be allowed, so real solution goes here - unpack variant, **87 chars**:

```
say map{y/01/ #/r}unpack"((b6)9a)*",'E`D@HB@Hd
EcD@HB@Hd
ggDsIbaIf
e`dDhRRHE
ECICPaQPf'
```

Output:

[image]

More elegant variant at 98 chars:

```
map{print$"x$_,$/x/1/,"#"x!/7/}7&ord,7&ord>>3for'PW{nw^QD[w}vK@X@PcP@jCDjXQk[rRRbSQD\CWbXeX'=~/./g
```

Output:

[image]

Older solution (114 chars), different type of coding:

```
print'#'x(3&ord),$"x($:=15&ord>>2),$/x!$:for'EmM}U}]MBEQSM}U}]MBOFNMQOKUMSKUOBEM]MMM]IIIMIUQIAEQWMMgFROYQOB'=~/./g
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Forgot the exclamation at the end, i.e. Hello-World! Also, should be lower-case `e`, but I know you did upper-case to make it readable as a five pixel high font...

Answer (score 47):

## JavaScript, 178 bytes

```
c=document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");c.fillText("Hello-World!",0,7);d=c.getImageData(1,0,56,7).data;s="";for(i=3;i<1568;i+=4){s+=d[i]?"#":" ";s+=(i+1)%224?"":"\n"}
```

That works in Firefox 27 Scratchpad.

```
#   #        #  #          #   #   #          #     #  #
#   #        #  #          #  # #  #          #     #  #
#   #   ##   #  #   ##      # # # #   ##   ## #   ###  #
#####  #  #  #  #  #  #     # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
#   #  ####  #  #  #  # ##  # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
#   #  #     #  #  #  #     # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #   
#   #   ###  #  #   ##       #   #    ##   #  #   ###  #
```

Comment: I recognise Arial :-D

Comment: This is my favourite. You've used an interesting method to arrive at the solution. Wonderful!

Comment: Ingenious, I do believe you've just created Figlet for JavaScript ;)

Comment: Dagnammit, this was my first thought too! Here's an upvote instead. :)

Answer (score 37):

## Mathematica <s>101 99</s> 98

This rasterizes the expression, obtains the binary image data, converts each 1 to "#", each 0 to "" (empty space) and displays output in a 12 by 130 character grid.

```
GraphicsGrid[ImageData@ImageResize[Binarize@Rasterize@Style["Hello-World!",99],130] 
  /.{1→"",0→"#"}]
```

[image: hello]

One character economized thanks to Jonathan Van Matre.

Comment: Why does the thickness vary between the l's?

Comment: I did the rasterization on the expression as a single image. If I had done it letter by letter, the l's would have been identical. Also, by increasing the rasterization grid size, the output tends to approach the quality of the printed characters. But a larger grid results in relatively smaller "#", to the point that they appear to be mere pixels.  The question remains: why do 2 l's in an image receive different weights?

Comment: @MrZander, that's the very reason fonts have hinting: When trying to fit fonts into a low-resolution pixel grid, like in ASCII art or on screen stem width is never really uniform because the font cannot have integral-pixel wide stems at all sizes. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/tools/trtalr.aspx) is a nice explanation with pictures.

Comment: @Joey, nice explanation and link.

Comment: prbably the best looking

Comment: Clever exploitation of Binarize@Rasterize. You can save a few bytes using 9 and 99 in place of 130 and 130. The output is somewhat less pretty, but still both readable and recognizably composed of #s.

Comment: Jonathan Van Matre, Thanks. The first parameter could  be reduced to 99 but I wouldn't want to reduce the second, due to output quality. (I realize that this is a code-golf challenge, but I do have my pride.)

Answer (score 26):

### Delphi 85 bytes

```
var s:tstringlist;begin s:=tstringlist.Create;s.LoadFromFile('\a');Write(s.Text);end.
```

I know, its not the prettiest solution but there was no rule that said you couldnt use external resources.
Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: +1 for the creativity of using # as background rather than foreground.

Comment: You can declare s as `TStrings` instead. (But keep the instantiation with `TStringList`.)

Comment: Is the file you're loading from something that actually ships with Delphi, or did you write it yourself? If the latter, I think you'd need to count its length as part of your score.

Comment: @Ilmari, I'm sure Delphi doesn't ship with a file with "Hello-World" ASCII art :) Moreover, it's described in the answer, that it uses external resources.

Comment: @TLama: I assumed so, too, I was just trying to phrase it politely. My point is that, *even if* external resources were allowed, this program would still fail on anyone's computer except its author's (and, in fact, we have no *proof* that it even works on his computer).  Also, I can beat his score with the following Perl script: `do X`. The content of the "external resource" `X` is left unspecified (it works for me, isn't that enough?), but I've provided a couple of [possible suggestions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20246) below...

Answer (score 15):

## Perl 5, 54 bytes / 71 printable ASCII chars

> **Note:** This is the second version of this answer.  For the original 64-byte / 95-char version using PHP and gzinflate(), see [the history of this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/20246/revisions).

Here's the 71-char printable ASCII version:

```
y/01/ #/,say for unpack'(B40)4',unpack u,'4I*`1`(JJI!$FFNRJU52HIJ0*))H'
```

The 54-byte version contains non-printable characters, so I'm providing it as a hex dump.  On Unixish systems, you can use `xxd -r` to turn the hex dump back into an executable Perl script:

```
0000000: 792f 3031 2f20 232f 2c73 6179 2066 6f72  y/01/ #/,say for
0000010: 2075 6e70 6163 6b27 2842 3430 2934 272c   unpack'(B40)4',
0000020: 27a4 a011 008a aaa4 1126 9aec aad5 54a8  '........&....T.
0000030: a6a4 0a24 9a27                           ...$.'
```

Both need to be run with `perl -M5.010` to enable the Perl 5.10+ `say` feature.  They will produce the following output:

[image: Screenshot of "Hello-World!" ASCII art]

(Shown as a screenshot, because the huge line-height on SE makes ASCII art ugly and hard to read.  The lower case "e" is kind of awkward, but I believe this qualifies as readable, if only barely so.)

---

**Ps.** If the output of the solution above feels too minimalistic for you, here's a **92-character** variant that produces output similar to [Tomas's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20228):

```
y/01/ #/,say for unpack'(B56)*',unpack u,'CH!(`"(`"":,2``B``@GGDC\'(C#(YI!)("I)"2*,),`4,03D'
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of "Hello-World!" ASCII art]

---

**Pps.** I'm pretty sure *this* (**GolfScript, 51 chars**) is the shortest printable-ASCII solution, if you don't count the ones that just call banner / FIGLet or that cheat in some other way:

```
'iJ@Q@HmURBIMM{JkUUJeMRAQIM'{2base(;{' #'=}/}%39/n*
```

The output is the same as for my 71-char Perl solution above.

Comment: I'd say you have just crossed the border of readability :-)

Comment: It's considerably more readable in my terminal than here on SE, because of the huge line spacing here.

Comment: I mean, it is unreadable anyway. BTW [I can produce your output in 92 chars](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20228/2800), with no external compression algorithm :-)

Comment: @Tomas: You're right, zipping does not seem to be the winning answer here. I'd give you a +1 for that if I hadn't already. BTW, I can do it in 71 chars; see above. :-)

Comment: @Tomas: ps. I added a version that produces output similar to yours.

Comment: The bottommost line of the 93-char like-Tomas's-output solution seems to be garbled for me.

Comment: Ilmari, you shouldn't have challenged me with `unpack` :-) Found a solution of 69 chars (87 with the nice output of mine).

Comment: @FireFly: Huh, you're right, there was a stray backslash in the code. I've no idea how it ended up in there, but I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 8):

## Shell + Figlet (35)

```
$ figlet -w 90 -f banner Hello-World!
#     #                                   #     #                             ### 
#     # ###### #      #       ####        #  #  #  ####  #####  #      #####  ### 
#     # #      #      #      #    #       #  #  # #    # #    # #      #    # ### 
####### #####  #      #      #    # ##### #  #  # #    # #    # #      #    #  #  
#     # #      #      #      #    #       #  #  # #    # #####  #      #    #     
#     # #      #      #      #    #       #  #  # #    # #   #  #      #    # ### 
#     # ###### ###### ######  ####         ## ##   ####  #    # ###### #####  ###
```

Comment: What kind of font is this? Those just look like smaller upper-case characters.

Comment: it's banner `-f banner` It was the first font I found that used # instead of * or | and _.

Comment: here's [the same in pure Python](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20279/1004)

Comment: Changing "90" to "9" yields a tall and skinny hello world, however because the OP does not care about columns or rows, it should be acceptable.

Comment: Sometimes voters baffle me.  How come this gets a net score of +8, but [the other figlet answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20334/11259) gets a net score of -3?

Answer (score 8):

### Python <strike>260 215 186</strike> 152

```
>>> print'eJyNkFEKwDAIQ/93isC7/x3LyIJullHrR1BfJSIJPUHTlmiUPHbxC7L56wNCgZAxv3SjDWIxsoOb\nzMaBwyHYPJ5sVPNYxXism74vcIsFZlYyrg=='.decode('base64').decode('zip')
#   #        #  #          #   #   #          #     #  #
#   #        #  #          #  # #  #          #     #  #
#   #   ##   #  #   ##      # # # #   ##   ## #   ###  #
#####  #  #  #  #  #  #     # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
#   #  ####  #  #  #  # ##  # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
#   #  #     #  #  #  #     # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #   
#   #   ###  #  #   ##       #   #    ##   #  #   ###  #
```

### Python <strike>196 183 130</strike> 114 (but uglyer)

```
>>> print'eJxTVlBWgCAgAQHKqBywAJeyAgJCZREcZWUYyaUMIpUVEKqRNcLEueDqEaZBLVVWQDITADIdFBw='.decode('base64').decode('zip')
# #  #  # #        # # #        #   # #
# # # # # #  #     # # #  #  ## #  ## #
### ##  # # # # ## # # # # # #  # # #
# #  ## # #  #      # #   #  #  #  ## #
```

I used zipped data in base64 encoding. and the code decode it from base64 encoding and then unzipping it.

Comment: Wow, that's really stretching legibility!

Answer (score 7):

## PHP — 183 bytes

Using sebcap26's ASCII art as the source...

```
foreach(str_split(base64_decode('iASAERACCYgEgBKQAgmIxIwKoxo5+SSSCqSSSYnkksqkkkmJBJIKpJJIiOSMBEMSOQ'))as$i=>$j)echo strtr(sprintf("%8s%s",decbin(ord($j)),($i+1)%7?"":"\n"),'01',' #');

#   #        #  #          #   #   #          #     #  #
#   #        #  #          #  # #  #          #     #  #
#   #   ##   #  #   ##      # # # #   ##   ## #   ###  #
#####  #  #  #  #  #  #     # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
#   #  ####  #  #  #  # ##  # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
#   #  #     #  #  #  #     # # # #  #  #  #  #  #  #   
#   #   ###  #  #   ##       #   #    ##   #  #   ###  #
```

Answer (score 6):

### Brainfuck, 372 Byte

(I know. but just for completeness, there has to be brainfuck ^^ It'S not going to get much shorter, as there are little repetitions. First and second line loop already...)

```
++++++++[>++++>++++<<-]>+++>>++++++++++>>+>++[-<<<<<.>.<.>..>>>[-<<<.>>>]<[-<<<.>>>]<<..<.>>>++[-<<.<.>..........<.>....>>]<<<.>.<.>>.>+>>]<<<<<...>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<.>..<..>..<...>.<.>..<.>..<.>..<..>...<..>.<.>..<...>.<.>>.<<.>.<.>.<.>...<.>.<.>.<.>..<.>.....<.>.<...>.<.>.<.>..<.>.<.>...<.>.<.>..<.>>.<<.>.<.>.<...>.<.>.<.>..<..>.......<..>.<..>...<..>..<.>...<.>..<..>..<.
```

Interpreter here: http://koti.mbnet.fi/villes/php/bf.php

---

```
# #     # #          #     #          #    # #
# #  #  # #          #     #          #    # #
### # # # #  ##  ### #  #  #  ##   ## #  ### #
# # #   # # #  #     # ### # #  # #   # #  #
# # ### # #  ##       ## ##   ##  #   #  ##  #
```

---

Combining @ASKASK's number generator and image with my loops and some additional tuning, we get:

### Brainfuck, <s>343 339 336</s>  334 Bytes

Looks uglier than my original version though.

```
+++++[->++++++>+++++++>++<<<]>++>>>+>>++[-<<<<.<.>.<..>>>[-<<<.>>>]>[-<<<.>>>]<<<<..>.<.>>>++[-<<.<.........>.<...>>>]<<.<.>.>.>>+>]<<<<..<<+++++[->>.<.<]>.>.<..>...<.>.<.>.<.>.<..>.<...>..<.>.<..>..<.>.>.<.<.>.<.>.<...>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<.....<++++++[->>.<.<]>..>.<.>.<.>.>.<.<.>.<..>.<..>.<.>.<..>.<.......>...<...>.<..>.<...>.<..>.<..>.
```

(image see @ASKASK's Answer)

Answer (score 5):

## EcmaScript 6, <strike>172</strike> 161

```
'¡I%e!c0ĄJ¥eìo0¸ËefMs0µKcÊIs0´Ê¢1éo'.split(0).map(s=>s.split('').map(c=>{for(i=8,s='';i--;)s+=(c.charCodeAt(0)-33)&(1<<i)?'#':' ';return s;}).join('')).join('\n')
```

Output:

```
#         # #        #   #   #           #    #
###   ##  # #  ##    #   #   #  ##  # ## #  ###
#  # #### # # #  #   #   #   # #  # ##   # #  #
#  # #    # # #  #    # # # #  #  # #    # #  #
#  #  ### # #  ##      #   #    ##  #    #  ###
```

Explanation:

> The ASCII text is compacted into a string where each bit represent a *pixel*:
>
> - `0` for `SPACE`
> - `1` for `#`
>
> An offset of 33 is applied in order to get only printable characters.

Comment: The first fat arrow function's brackets and `return` statement are not necessary.

Comment: @manatwork I tried to removed it but then it was no longer compiling. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Firefox 27.0: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VyqnC.png

Comment: `charCodeAt(0)` can be [reduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) to `charCodeAt()`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting), 38 characters (76 bytes)

```
갦륈똄릵꺕녔꺒녪냕녪낷뚕년꺒녦냉괄낵要감嚙긂밃⓶掘⓶終丟併껧뜴꼧밍替現겠合終
```

### Output:

```
# # ## #  #   #     #   #  #  ##  #  ##  #
# # #  #  #  # #    #   # # # # # #  # # #
### ## #  #  # # ## # # # # # ##  #  # # #
# # #  #  #  # #    # # # # # # # #  # #  
# # ## ## ##  #      # #   #  # # ## ##  #
```

Comment: The code-golf [info page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) says "If you use Unicode, byte count should use UTF-8." If I'm not mistaken, that makes your program-length **114 bytes**. (The 76 bytes you mention would be for UTF-16 without a BOM.)

Comment: @r.e.s.: I changed that, as it makes no sense to require that. My Sclipting interpreter understands UTF-16 just fine, so it’s a valid program encoded as UTF-16.

Comment: Timwi, case matters

Comment: Shouldn't this be 'Hello-World" and not "HELLO-WORLD"

Comment: @user689 - actually "Hello-World!" with an exclamation point at the end...

Comment: A mix between Korean and Chinese/Japanese ideographs.  I thought those were only used for people's names in Korean now.  Interesting.

Comment: Oh, I see why now.

Comment: I see that you edited the [info page](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-golf/info) for the `code-golf` tag.  It might have been a better idea to first propose and discuss such changes -- e.g. in response to [Scoring code golf (bytes vs. characters)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/942/scoring-code-golf-bytes-vs-characters).

Comment: @r.e.s.: Actually my edit *was* a proposal and it has been accepted by the community. (I don’t have the rep to edit it directly.)

Comment: I suppose "accepted by the community" means "accepted, *without community discussion*, by a small number of people with the power to do so."

Comment: @r.e.s.: I apologize for any friction caused by my (and the reviewers’) actions. I didn’t realize that this was controversial. Please consider giving me the benefit of the doubt. I *am* engaging in community discussion about this on meta now.

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 362 bytes

Sorry @johannes-h, I saw yours and was inspired to make my own. It uses a combination of faster number generation at the beginning and a simpler picture to generate the result in less bytes. It does not however use loops anywhere else so it is up for optimization.

```
+++++[->++++++>+++++++>++<<<]>++>.<.>.<.....>.<.>.<.........>.<...>.<.........>.<...>.<.>.>.<.<.>.<..>.<..>.<.>.<.........>.<...>.<.........>.<...>.<.>.>.<...<.>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<..>.<..>...<.>.<.>.<.>.<..>.<...>..<.>.<..>..<.>.>.<.<.>.<.>.<...>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<.....>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<.>.<...>.<.>.<.>.>.<.<.>.<..>.<..>.<.>.<..>.<.......>...<...>.<..>.<...>.<..>.<..>.
```

which generates:

[image: pic]

Comment: Hm. How much shorter is the number generation? 'cause changing the image looks like cheating to me (at least when directly comparing our solutions - perfectly valid in this contest of course) ^^ BUt I'm going to look into yours later on :)

You can take my loop for the first two lines however. It's a lot shorter (was about 10-20 bytes if I remember correctly)

Comment: got your version down to 343 Byte, see my answer

Comment: and even shorter, replacing more repetitions by loops. 339 now.

Comment: I dont have neough reputation to comment on yours but if you look closely at your new version you will find a "><" in there that can be deleted to take away two bytes :)

Answer (score 3):

## ImageMagick + sed, 71 bytes

I don't see any other ImageMagick entries, so here's my late stake in the ground:

```
convert +antialias label:Hello-World! xpm:-|sed '8,+9y/ /#/;s/[^#]/ /g'
```

I think the `sed` portion can probably be golfed some more.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@cn1eWWlSioJ2YV5KZmJOZWKyQk5iUmmPlkZqTk68bnl@Uk6KoUFGQa6VbU5yaoqBuoaNtWamvoK@sb12sHx2nHAtkp6v//w8A).

Output:

```
         
  #    #          #  #            ##   #    #            #      #  #     
  #    #          #  #             #   ##  ##            #      #  #     
  #    #          #  #             #  ###  #             #      #  #     
  #    #   ####   #  #  ####       #  # #  #  ####   # # #  ### #  #     
  ######  #    #  #  # ##  ##      #  # #  # ##  ##  ##  # ##  ##  #     
  #    #  ######  #  # #    # ###   # #  # # #    #  #   # #    #  #     
  #    #  #       #  # #    #       ##   ##  #    #  #   # #    #  #     
  #    #  ##  ##  #  # ##  ##       ##   ##  ##  ##  #   # ##  ##        
  #    #   ####   #  #  ####        ##   ##   ####   #   #  ### #  #
```

Answer (score 2):

### **Postscript, <s>154</s> 133**

```
<~GasbQ8I>GO#QsOD7:?,pa&5XCgo@jeLPX:a4F9kN1nu1B@8KjD"^]WgY[MA.2VBjpTNo5$Pi%uI9Lr>,9`~>/FlateDecode filter 999 string readstring pop =
```

i.e.

```
    <~GasbQ8I>GO#QsOD7:?,pa&5XCgo@jeLPX:a4F9kN1nu1B@8KjD"^]WgY[MA.2VBjpTNo5$Pi%uI
9Lr>,9`~>
/FlateDecode filter 
999 string readstring pop 
=
```

ASCII-only source, inspiration for ASCII-art was Johannes H.'s answer :-)

```
# #     # #         #    #          #    # #
# #  #  # #         #    #          #    # #
### # # # #  ##  ## #    #  ##   ## #  ### #
# # #   # # #  #    # ## # #  # #   # #  #
# # ### # #  ##      #  #   ##  #   #  ##  #
```

(more readable in terminal)

### **Perl, 102**

```
print$-%44?'':"\n",vec(unpack(u,'<!040`A!:4@`A`*%7918REEM1":T4)75E(#&1"0``'),$-++,1)?'#':' 'for 0..219
```

Same output as above. I know I lost to both Perl answers above, but I publish it anyway. At least I tried and was moving in the right direction (and hadn't seen shortest answer) :-).

Answer (score 2):

## Pure Bash, no external utilities - 133 characters:

```
c=" #";for x in 0x{5250088045,55520A914D,74556AAA54,535205124D};do while((s=(t=x)^(x/=2)*2,t));do L=${c:s:1}$L;done;echo "$L";L=;done
```

Uses right and left shift (divide and multiply by 2) and xor to find the one bits.

Font data stolen from Blender/Ilmari Karonen.

Tested in Bash 3.2 and 4.2

By the way, this is only 166 characters:

```
echo "# #  #  # #        #   #        #   # #
# # # # # #  #     # # #  #   # #  ## #
### #   # # # # ## # # # # # #  # # #  
# #  ## # #  #      # #   #  #  #  ## #"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 114

```
print('\n'.join(bin(x)[2:]for x in[353530052677,366448644429,499649260116,357858349645]).translate({48:32,49:35}))
```

Output (4-character tall **e** and **W** stolen from [@Ilmari Karonen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/20246/7800)):

```
# #  #  # #        #   #        #   # #
# # # # # #  #     # # #  #   # #  ## #
### #   # # # # ## # # # # # #  # # #  
# #  ## # #  #      # #   #  #  #  ## #
```

And a shorter one (107):

```
print('\n'.join(bin(x)[2:]for x in[11993933918769,16391913257513,12021315382193]).translate({48:32,49:35}))
```

Output:

```
# # ### #   #   ###   # # ### ##  #   ##   #
### ### #   #   # #   # # # # ### #   # #  #
# # ### ### ### ###   ### ### # # ### ##   #
```

Comment: It's mostly unreadable. Your World from 2nd output is actually Uorld.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: It looks better on an actual terminal emulator. Also, "Human-readable" gives you a bit of wiggle room. I'm sure you can guess what `"HELLO ⊔ORLD!" means.

Comment: Use hex constants and shave a few characters off

Comment: @Floris: I tried that. The two-character prefix makes them just as long up until around 20 digits.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 154 Characters, (Char 5X7 in size)

```
print'\n'.join(map(''.join,zip(*(''.join("# "[int(e)]for e in"{:07b}".format(ord(c))[1:])for c in"€÷÷÷€ÿñêêòÿ€ÿ€ÿñîîñÿûûÿŸáþÁ¿ÁþáŸÿñîîñÿàïÿ€ÿÿñîî€ÿ‚"))))
```

**Output**

```
#   #      # #         #   #   #         #     # #
#   #      # #         #  # #  #         #     # #
#   #  ##  # #  ##      # # # #   ##  ## #   ### #
##### #  # # # #  #     # # # #  #  # #  #  #  # #
#   # #### # # #  # ##  # # # #  #  # #  #  #  # #
#   # #    # # #  #     # # # #  #  # #  #  #  #  
#   #  ### # #  ##       #   #    ##  #  #   ### #
```

Answer (score 1):

## bash, <s>175</s> 170 bytes

You need to *waste* quite a few characters in order to produce a *pretty output*!

```
base64 -d<<<H4sICKaT9FICAzAxAK2RQQ7AIAgE776CZP7/x1ZjERebcJAL0QybhcV6YdWizAPNaUatQQLFpj6h+c/XA05WF9Wtk9WJcxz4oe6e1YPQa7Wiut2wfjJ16STY30lSnNIlzvdpHhd6MiTOB65NYc+LAgAA|zcat
```

Output:

```
#     #                                         #     #                                   ###
#     #  ######  #       #        ####          #  #  #   ####   #####   #       #####    ###
#     #  #       #       #       #    #         #  #  #  #    #  #    #  #       #    #   ###
#######  #####   #       #       #    #  #####  #  #  #  #    #  #    #  #       #    #    #
#     #  #       #       #       #    #         #  #  #  #    #  #####   #       #    #
#     #  #       #       #       #    #         #  #  #  #    #  #   #   #       #    #   ###
#     #  ######  ######  ######   ####           ## ##    ####   #    #  ######  #####    ###
```

Comment: You can make it smaller with lzma/unlzma

Answer (score 1):

Shell, 20 characters:

```
banner Hello-world\!
```

For this to work, of course you need the `banner` program.  On Debian, you can get it by installing the `bsdmainutils` package.

This prints a beautifully rendered version of your message, designed to be printed on one of the old continuous-feed printers, so the output of the above text is 322 lines long by 123 columns wide, and you turn the printout on its side to read the message.  You could hang the resulting paper on the wall as a banner, hence the name.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_%28Unix%29

EDIT: Looks like Debian also has the `sysvbanner` package, which installs a banner program that prints the text horizontally for display on a terminal.  However, this only prints the first 10 characters of the message, so it is kind of annoying for this code-golf problem!

Comment: I believe you meant to write `banner hello-world`.

Comment: @Floris, thanks for the heads-up.  Fixed.

Comment: Note that banner appeared on Unix v7 in 1979 and is found on virtually every Unix.

Comment: @sch, I agree that `banner` is available for virtually every UNIX.  I just put the Debian package as a convenient proof that I wasn't just making something up, for people who didn't know about it.  These days I wouldn't expect to find `banner` installed by default on a UNIX, any more than I would expect to find a continuous-feed printer in a computer lab anymore.  But any code golf on making banner text really ought to have the `banner` program in it somewhere.  It's part of our rich cultural history as computer geeks.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Bash:

### (<del>103</del> 89 Bytes)

#### Code:

```
base64 -d<<<rohBEmRiqIihFVRS7IitVWRSqIihVVRQru5Aoldi|xxd -b|sed -e's/ //g;s/1/#/g;s/0/ /g'|cut -b'9-55'
```

#### Output:

```
# # ### #   #    #     #   #  #  ##  #   ##   #
# # #   #   #   # #    #   # # # # # #   # #  #
### ##  #   #   # # ## # # # # # ##  #   # #  #
# # #   #   #   # #    # # # # # # # #   # #   
# # ### ### ###  #      # #   #  # # ### ##   #
```

Smaller, but less readable (Based on http://mckgyver.pbworks.com/f/1240440791/3PixelFont.jpg):

#### Code:

```
base64 -d<<<V0nCLsmQdklaqslQV23BTq2Q|xxd -b|sed -e's/ //g;s/1/#/g;s/0/ /g;'|cut -c'9-52'
```

#### Output:

```
 # # ### #  #  ###    #   # ### ##  #  ##  #
 ### ##  #  #  # # ## # # # # # ##  #  # # #
 # # ### ## ## ###     # #  ### # # ## ##  #
```

Answer (score 1):

Authors: xem, aemkei, p01, jonas

Execute this in the JS console.

### JavaScript, cross-browser,<s>133</s> <s>132</s> <s>126</s> 117 bytes

```
for(i=s="";l=[43117609029,64070269789,46349920852,46890400349][i++];)for(j=0,s+="\n";c=l.toString(2)[j++];)s+=" #"[c]
```

### JavaScript, ES6, works on Firefox, 108 bytes

```
[,0xa0a028045,0xeeae2bb5d,0xacaabaa54,0xaeae2ba5d].map(a=>a.toString(2).replace(/./g,b=>' #'[b])).join('\n')
```

### Result:

```
>
# #     # #       # #        #   # #
### ### # # ###   # # ### ## # ### #
# # ##  # # # # # ### # # #  # # #  
# # ### # # ###   # # ### #  # ### #
```

Comment: @p01 made a shorter version (118 bytes) here: https://twitter.com/p01/status/433230019419471872

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript / ES6 (108 bytes)

Copy into console:

```
[,0xa0a028045,0xeeae2bb5d,0xacaabaa54,0xaeae2ba5d].map(a=>a.toString(2).replace(/./g,b=>' #'[b])).join('\n')
```

Output:

```
"
# #     # #       # #        #   # #
### ### # # ###   # # ### ## # ### #
# # ##  # # # # # ### # # #  # # #  
# # ### # # ###   # # ### #  # ### #"
```

(Needs ECMAScript6 compatible browser ie. Firefox 22+)

Inspired by @maximeeuziere, @p01, @aemkei

Comment: `.join('\n')` can be reduced to `.join(\`



\`)` where the space is an actual new line character.

Answer (score 1):

## HTML, 209 characters

```html
<pre># #     # #                      #   # #
# #     # #        # # #         #   # #
###  ## # #  #     # # #  #  ##  #  ## #
# # ##  # # # # ## # # # # # # # # # #
# # ### # #  #      # #   #  #   # ### #</pre>
```

Does this count? :)

Answer (score 0):

**F# - 204 characters**

```
for s in(Seq.map(Seq.unfold(function|0L->None|i->Some(" #".[int(i%2L)],i/2L)))[173948798213L;174770890021L;191304848727L;182715110773L;45277009173L;191279670629L])do printfn"%s"(new string(Seq.toArray s))
```

Output:

```
# #     # #        # #         #   # #
# #  #  # #  #     # #  #   ## #   # #
### # # # # # #    # # # # #   #  ## #
# # ### # # # # ## # # # # #   # # # #
# # #   # # # #    ### # # #   # # #  
# #  ## # #  #     # #  #  #   #  ## #
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python + [pyfiglet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyfiglet/) -- 87 characters

```
from pyfiglet import figlet_format     
print(figlet_format('Hello-World!', font='banner'))
```

#### Output

```
#     #                                   #     #                             ### 
#     # ###### #      #       ####        #  #  #  ####  #####  #      #####  ### 
#     # #      #      #      #    #       #  #  # #    # #    # #      #    # ### 
####### #####  #      #      #    # ##### #  #  # #    # #    # #      #    #  #  
#     # #      #      #      #    #       #  #  # #    # #####  #      #    #     
#     # #      #      #      #    #       #  #  # #    # #   #  #      #    # ### 
#     # ###### ###### ######  ####         ## ##   ####  #    # ###### #####  ###
```

To install `pyfiglet`, run:

```
$ pip install pyfiglet
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python with pyfiglet: 66 using argv, 69 without

### 66:

```
from pyfiglet import*
print(figlet_format(sys.argv[1],font='3x5'))
```

### 69:

```
from pyfiglet import*
print(figlet_format('Hello-World!',font='3x5'))
```

firs must be called as, for example:

python asciiart.py 'Hello-World!'

second:

python asciiart.py.

Output:

```
    # #      #   #          # #          #    #  #  
    # # ###  #   #  ###     # # ### ###  #  ###  #  
    ### ##   #   #  # # ### ### # # #    #  # #  #  
    # # ###  ##  ## ###     ### ### #    ## ###     
    # #                     # #                  #
```

(Well, it looks kinda crappy with this font. Nevertheless :) )

[edit] removed obsolete dash from the argument.

Comment: Why the extra dash in front of the output?

Comment: My mistake, that's the output from the one using argv, where I used a dash before the argument (matter of habit, as I use bash all the time). I'll edit it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 137 (134)

Uses the bits of integers to represent sharps an white spaces.
Tested with Firefox 27.

**137 character**

```
s="";[0xadb73eead9,g=0xa9252aaa94,0xed252aac95,g+1,0xad272aee99].map(n=>{for(;n>0;n/=2)n%2?[s="#"+s,n--]:s=" "+s;s="\n"+s});console.log(s)

# # ## #  #  ###  # # # ### ### #  ##  #
# # #  #  #  # #  # # # # # # # #  # # #
### ## #  #  # #  # # # # # ##  #  # # #
# # #  #  #  # #  # # # # # # # #  # #  
# # ## ## ## ###  ##### ### # # ## ##  #"
```

**134 character (rotated 180°)**

```
s="";[0xadb73eead9,g=0xa9252aaa94,0xed252aac95,g+1,0xad272aee99].map(n=>{s+="\n";for(;n>0;n/=2)n%2?[s+="#",n--]:s+=" "});console.log(s)

"
#  ## ## # # ### #####  ### ## ## ## # #
  # #  # # # # # # # #  # #  #  #  # # #
# # #  #  ## # # # # #  # #  #  # ## ###
# # #  # # # # # # # #  # #  #  #  # # #
#  ##  # ### ### # # #  ###  #  # ## # #"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python3 (126)

There's an additional space between the chars to make it better readable. So technically it's a 125 character solution.

```
print(' '.join(['','\n'][i%40==0]+['#',' '][int('72liw1j4glyc34dum02j2a4ipxa8b7vvp65x511',36)//2**i%2==0]for i in range(200)))
```

Output:

```
#   #   # #   #     #     # # #     #   #   #   # # #   # # #   #     # #     # 
#   #   #     #     #     #   #     #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #     #   #   # 
# # #   # #   #     #     #   #     #   #   #   #   #   # #     #     #   #   # 
#   #   #     #     #     #   #     #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #     #   #     
#   #   # #   # #   # #   # # #     # # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #   # #     #
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash <s>37</s>, 33

```
toilet<<<"Hello-world"|tr \"m \#

 #    #        ###    ###                                       ###        # 
 #    #  ###     #      #     ###         #     #  ###    # ##    #     #### 
 ###### ##  #    #      #    ## ##        ## # ## ## ##   ##  #   #    ## ## 
 #    # #####    #      #    #   #   ###   #####  #   #   #       #    #   # 
 #    # #####    ###    ###  #####          # #   #####   #       ###  #####
```

Which is the same as:

```
echo "Hello-world" | toilet
```

From `man toilet`

> TOIlet - display large colourful character

With `tr "'\"m" "#"` all `"` chars are replaced with `#`.

Comment: `tr`'s parameters would be shorter escaped than quoted. I mean `tr \'\"m \#` instead of `tr "'\"m" "#"`.

Comment: Oh good one, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks @manatwork

Comment: Wait a second. The `toilet` output had no single quote. Why you included it in `tr`'s 1st parameter? Just `tr \"m \#` is enough.

Comment: @manatwork I think I need more coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk, 151

although this golf game is already over, for the reference:

```
i:=((Form extent:115@14)displayString:'Hello world'x:0y:12;asImage).0to:13 do:[:y|i valuesAtY:y from:0to:114 do:[:x :p|({$#.$ }at:p+1)print].Stdout cr]
```

output:

```
 ***  ***             ***       ***                                                         ***           **       
  *    *                *         *                                                           *            *       
  *    *                *         *                                                           *            *       
  *    *     ***        *         *        ***              ***   ***    ***     *** ***      *        *** *       
  ******    *   *       *         *       *   *              *     *    *   *      **   *     *       *   **       
  *    *   *     *      *         *      *     *             *  *  *   *     *     *          *      *     *       
  *    *   *******      *         *      *     *              * * *    *     *     *          *      *     *       
  *    *   *            *         *      *     *              * * *    *     *     *          *      *     *       
  *    *    *    *      *         *       *   *               ** **     *   *      *          *       *   **       
 ***  ***    ****    *******   *******     ***                *   *      ***     ******    *******     *** **
```

Comment: You have to only use ' '(spaces) and '#' characters(also newline characters).

Comment: my mistake; the output was from a previous run; the code is correct "{$#.$ }at:p+1".

Answer (score 0):

**C#, <del>205</del> <del>203</del> 202 bytes**

I'm storing the text as an array of 5 longs, each representing a row in the display. I iterate over the array, and use bitwise comparison to work out if each bit is a # (1) or a space (0).

```cs
class G{static void Main(){foreach(var c in new long[]{0x14401100505,0x16589102525,0x15455575557,0x5455505535,0x16448A02565})for(int i=0;i<42;i++)System.Console.Write((i>40)?"\n":(c&1L<<i)>0?"#":" ");}}
```

Answer (score -1):

## "cURL", 16 characters:

> program: (computer science) a sequence of instructions that a computer can interpret and execute;

```
curl floris.us/h
```

Produces:

```
#   #      #  #           #   #          #     #  #
#   #  ##  #  #   ##      #   #  ##   ## #   ###  #
##### #### #  #  #  # ### # # # #  # #   #  #  #  #
#   # #    #  #  #  #     # # # #  # #   #  #  #
#   #  ##   #  #  ##       # #   ##  #    #  ###  #
```

I guess if I had a cooler domain, it would be shorter...

Comment: Personally, I would consider this cheating.

Comment: @RyanCarlson yes, but it's short...

Comment: @RyanCarlson It isn't any worse than using figlet.

Comment: How is this different from putting an arbitrarily large program into a script called `x`, setting execute permission on `x`, setting the `PATH` to include the current directory, and then saying you have a one-character solution (just type `x`!).  I think this whole class of solution is cheating.

Comment: @mojo, figlet is at least a common program, to which people have access.  Some people already have it installed, and others can install it.  I don't think it's "cheating" to use such a program.  But I do think this problem would be better if it required answers to be written in a programming language and not run any external programs or include any library modules.  (That would of course invalidate my own answer, which depends on the user having the `banner` program installed.)

Comment: @steveha - The only "difference" I can offer is that this "program" is available on your computer already - no scripts to write etc. Those operations would be additional key strokes that you would have to count. This - no extra key strokes needed on your computer. I agree it is a weak defense, but not much worse than `banner` or others like it. Agree with your suggested improvement of the question though.

Comment: @steveha The reason I wouldn't use figlet or banner is because they do all the ASCII art work for you. It seems like that was the heart of the challenge. "Cheating" might be an overstatement, but I wouldn't consider _my own_ entry very legitimate if I used it.

Comment: I'd agree that this is a cheeky/cheaty solution, but I will note that you *must* have an `http://` as part of the URL. Just because your fancy browser hides it doesn't mean it's not there. :)

Comment: @Floris You can transform your answer in a shell one: `curl floris.us/h` ;-)

Comment: @IonicăBizău - thanks for that suggestion! It does indeed work!

Answer (score -4):

## Shell + pyfiglet, 31 characters

pyfiglet can run as a shell tool, so we can simply go like this:

```
pyfiglet -f'3x5' 'Hello-World!'
```

which gives us:

```
# #      #   #          # #          #    #  #  
# # ###  #   #  ###     # # ### ###  #  ###  #  
### ##   #   #  # # ### ### # # #    #  # #  #  
# # ###  ##  ## ###     ### ### #    ## ###     
# #                     # #                  #
```

Looks much better with less line spacing.

Letters are separated with one space, and in terminal it's well readable.

Comment: You could save two chars by [just dropping the `py`](http://www.figlet.org/figlet-man.html). Also, there's no need to quote `3x5`.

Comment: Big rule abuse, nothing even remotely similar to golfing.

Comment: No need for any of those quotes

Comment: Why not just compile one of the other solutions in this post, and give the binary a one character name?

Comment: I provided this answer seeing others use bash+banner and bash+figlet, both external tools. If that's rule abuse, my other answer uses python 2.7 with pyfiglet. Is using an established library discouraged/prohibited?

Comment: Taku, the purpose of code golf should be to write a short program that solves the problem, not just call another program or library or whatever that already solves the very problem! Otherwise we might get to the extreme @The111 mentions. Well, it's a hole in the rules, it's your decision to abuse it or not. But think why did you get zero upvotes..

Comment: I see your point. Please excuse my misunderstanding, then, based on many answers in this - and other - topics, I got the idea that the purpose was just to write the shortest code possible, any hack goes, but that would indeed lead to calling some URL containing ASCIIart through curl, and, granted, it would be pointless. Thanks for pointing that out, I'm still new to the idea, and not a sesoned programmer as well. I'll keep my libraries in my pants next time :)