# Generate ASCII art from text

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Your challenge is to write a program which creates ASCII art from an input string, like [FIGlet](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIGlet) or the Unix [banner](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_%28Unix%29) utility.

Specifically, your program should take as input a string consisting of printable ASCII characters, and output an ASCII art representation of those characters in the order they appear in the input.

You're free to choose the details of what the output will look like, except that:

1. The output must be readable.
2. Simply representing each input character by itself in the output, with or without surrounding "decorative" characters, is considered cheating.

Also, you may not use any programs (like FIGlet), libraries or built-in tools designed for generating ASCII art, nor may your program rely on any external resources such as web services.

This is code golf, so the shortest program wins.

Comment: Here's my golfscript program, assuming input from command line:. Input whatever string you like, and the program will output ascii art.

Comment: @TonyH: I don't think it's a duplicate; this challenge seems to basically amount to "golf a simple [FIGlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIGlet) clone", while the challenge you linked to is about converting bitmap images to ASCII art. I do feel that this question is somewhat underspecified, though.

Comment: @user3103241: I've edited your challenge to hopefully make it a bit clearer, more specific and less open to abuse.  Let me know if you feel I've misrepresented the intent of your challenge.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was put on hold, when e.g. [Generating PBM bitmap files from ASCII text](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/generating-pbm-bitmap-files-from-ascii-text) (a very similar challenge, but asking for bitmap output instead of ASCII art) and [ASCII art “Hello-World!”](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/20209/ascii-art-hello-world) (similar, but with fixed input and some restrictions on output characters) seem to have been perfectly fine and successful challenges. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, I would say that "Generating PBM bitmap files" is so similar that this counts as a dupe.